# Laravel database design for natural language processing on text

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I have a database design question.

I am currently performing natural language processing on Twitter messages for intraday stocks data using three different NLP engines - Stanford NLP, IBM Watson, and OpinionFinder.

Both Stanford NLP and OpinionFinder use a polarity flag to denote sentiment - positive, neutral, and negative. I can identify this in the database a `-1`, `0`, `1`.

IBM Watson has five different percentages (from 0 - 100) on text known as anger, disgust, fear, joy, and sadness, and this can be stored as a float or integer (i.e. `0.9` or 90).

Each day (identified as `date`, in the format of `YYYY-mm-dd`) has three sentiment rows, one row for each NLP engine. So, there can be three identical `symbol_id` and `date`, which is why I think I should also add a `nlp_engine` to the composite unique key. My plan is to use `symbol_id date nlp_engine` as a composite unique key.

An alternative to this is, I also have a `Prices` table which stores the stock prices/futures data, and it has the following format:

`id | date | symbol_id | ...`

So, I **could** use the `Symbols.id` that references each day in `Sentiments.prices_id`, since I only gather intraday (daily) data.

Thus I want to create a table called `Sentiments` with the following columns:

`id | symbol_id | date | nlp_engine | anger | disgust | fear | joy | sadness | polarity | created_at | updated_at`

Explanation:

`id` - primary key

`symbol_id` (foreign key to a `Symbols table` which holds my stock symbols + a composite unique key to `date` and `nlp_engine` column)

`date` - (composite unique key with `symbol_id` and `nlp_engine`)

`nlp_engine` - (should I use a string for this or should I create a new table called NLPEngines and use a `nlp_engine_id`? This should also be a composite unique key with `symbol_id` and `date`)

`anger` - float

`disgust` - float

`fear` - float

`joy` - float

`sadness` - float

`polarity` - signed integer such as `-1`, `0`, `1`

I just want some critique on this database design - thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The structure of your data sounds solid, but it just depends on how you're going to store/retrieve this data.

1. This data is the result of calculations, if it needs to be real time and is disposable you may want to consider using something closer to a cache store or NoSql. But again, depends on your problem at hand.
2. Laravel is not particularly flexible when it comes to single table inheritance. You need to resolve the correct classes to handle the interactions between the different engines. If the `sentiments` table data does not need to be normalized, then you're going to be pigeonholing data from different engines into a format that's not going to make sense. You're almost better off creating 3 different tables, one for each engine.

However if you absolutely need to be able to tie multiple engine results to one `Price` then yes I think you're taking the right approach. I would recommend using accessors/mutators to normalize your data so the rest of your application doesn't have to know how to do it.

Comment: Hi Dylan. We are simply doing one processing of the messages and saving to the database once - it won't be a realtime thing, as we're simply looking at past data right now, Yeah.. I'm wondering if the 3 different NLP engines will be good to be stored in one database as each NLP engine stores its values slightly differently. Maybe I should do as you said - use a new table for each engine.